# Is it possible to replace text automatically in Notepad++ from the command line?

Tags: windows, replace, command-line, notepad++

I want to find and replace a string in a textfile using Notepad++ and I would like to do so automatically from the command line.

I want to replace ALL occurences of "userid=" with "userid=123456" in textfile mytextfile.txt

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N++ is an editing tool, not a file processing utility. One slightly possible solution would be to provide the name of a macro to run immediately as a file is opened.

Answer (score 6):

You can do in 3 steps:

1. Record a macro that performs the replacement
2. Open the file from the command line
3. Execute the macro

**To record a macro**:

1. Macro > Start Recording
2. Search > Repalce (or `Ctrl + H`)
3. Find: `userid=\d*`, Replace with: `userid=123456`, and check `Regular Exressions

[image: Replace with regular expression]

4. Click on "Replace All"  (or `Alt + A`)
5. Macro > Stop Recording
6. Macro > Save Current Recorder Macro

**To open from command line**:

Run `<notepad++ path> mytextfile.txt`. For example in Windows 64bits:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" mytextfile.txt
```

**To execute the macro**:

Go to "Macro" menu and select the previously recorded macro.

---

A better way to solve your problem is to use **Perl one-liner**.

1. Install Perl script language
2. Run the following command

`perl -i.bak -pe 's/userid=\d*/userid=123456/g' mytextfile.txt`

This command will copy the file in a backup `mytextfile.txt.bak` and replace all occurrences of "userid".

About Perl one-liner, this is a great page with some tips: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of

Cheers